# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel, http, ssl, curl

When in PHP aritsan database:seed and error occurs

**Full error:**

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://provinces.open-api.vn/api/p/
> at

C:\xampp\htdocs\appchanhxe\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:211

> ```
>     209▕         $error = isset($connectionErrors[$easy->errno])
>     210▕             ? new ConnectException($message, $easy->request, null, $ctx)
>   ➜ 211▕             : new RequestException($message, $easy->request, $easy->response, null, $ctx);
>     212▕
>     213▕         return P\Create::rejectionFor($error);
>     214▕     }
>     215▕
> ```

1   C:\xampp\htdocs\example\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:158
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle))

2   C:\xampp\htdocs\example\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:110
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))

I **tried** placing the cacert.pem file in the path C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
and change in php.ini curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem" but still this error occurs

Comment: (1) Apart from [curl], you need to add /amend the [openssl] part in your php.ini (2) make sure that the path is correct for cacert.pem (3) After the amendment, remember to restart the httpd service

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working in a development environment, you can solve this problem by opening the file `vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php`, then looking for a method called `configureDefaults()`, you will find the following code:

```
$defaults = [
    'allow_redirects' => RedirectMiddleware::$defaultSettings,
    'http_errors' => true,
    'decode_content' => true,
    'verify' => true, // <-- change to false
    'cookies' => false,
    'idn_conversion' => false,
];
```

The error happens because `guzzlehttp` uses `curl` under the hood, and setting the `verify` option to `false` disables the verification of the SSL certificate.

Notice that this approach isn't recommended for a production environment (e.g. live server) because it poses a security issue.

Edit: you will also need to repeat the same steps each time you run `composer install` since you're modifying files inside the `vendor` folder.

Comment: Is there a way that doesn't affect the environment and security?

Comment: @ThanhLuan In my opinion, I don't think you should worry about this in a development environment (e.g. your personal computer). I think that this issue is related to the configuration on XAMPP for Windows because I've never had this problem before on Linux. So I guess it's not a bad idea to tolerate it in your development environment.